# Variable declaration and initialization in JavaScript/Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

I have seen different recommendation of coding format/styles in JavaScript. One of them is to omit `,` and `;` at the end of each line unless the `,` is used in a JSON object. Another is to use only `var` to declare variables and indent 2nd variable onward.

I adopted both recommendation and this has caused me one interesting bug that I'd like to seek deeper understanding of the issue.

### Initialization

```
var max = 2
    arr = []
    wait = 10

//Preset arr with simple object {id:i}
for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) arr.push({id:i})
```

### Main Function

```
function simulate(idIn, callback) {
    var msg = idIn 
        id = idIn

    logger.info(idIn, 'simulate', JSON.stringify({id:id, idIn:idIn}))
    setTimeout(function() {
        var obj = {id:id, idIn:idIn}
        logger.info(idIn, 'init', JSON.stringify(obj))
        callback()
    }, wait)
}
```

### Paralleled Execution

```
async.map(arr, function(item, cb) {
    logger.info('map', JSON.stringify(item))
    simulate(item.id, cb)
}, function(err, result) {})
```

### Output

```
info: map {"id":0}
info: 0 'simulate' '{"id":0,"idIn":0}'
info: map {"id":1}
info: 1 'simulate' '{"id":1,"idIn":1}'
info: 0 'init' '{"id":1,"idIn":0}'  //id is overwritten here 
info: 1 'init' '{"id":1,"idIn":1}'
```

As you can see from the output, the local variable `id` is overwritten with incoming value of `idIn` parameter during the wait. I fixed the issue by simply adding a `,` in the variable declaration of the `simulate` function.

```
    var msg = idIn, //Added comma here. 
        id = idIn
```

I suppose this means `,` cannot be omitted in multiple variable declaration if you want to use only one `var` keyword. I'm trying to understand what happens to the 2nd variable `id` when `,` is omitted? Does this change its scope or it's made to something else?

Comment: Omitting the  `,` operator leads to automatic semicolon insertion (ASI): `var msg = idIn; id = idIn;` Now the `var` keyword is omitted. Since your variable declarations are in local scope, `id` gets a global variable.

Comment: I have found this post that may help you: http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/

Comment: Wherever you got this recommendation, don't visit that website again.

Comment: Worth mentioning that declaring 'use strict' would help you catch this sooner.

Comment: Thanks all. That clears the doubts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript, like every programming language, has its syntactical rules.
And I suggest you to study them, before following any kind of recommendation (and the one you have followed is terrible, IMHO).

One of these rules is that `;` (which is used to separate statements):

- is **required** when you have two (or more) statements on the same line
- is **optional** if the statement is followed by a line break

Another rule says that you have to use the `var` keyword to declare a variable, and its scope depends on where this declaration happens.

1. When you declare a variable inside a function, *e.g.*:

   ```
   function f() {
       var v;
   }
   ```

   the variable `v` will have a **local** scope, *i.e.* it can be only accessed within the function `f`.
2. Otherwise, when you declare a variable outside a function, *e.g.*:

   ```
   var v;
   ```

   the variable `v` will have a **global** scope, *i.e.* it can be accessed by every script and function on the same page.
3. Even if you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, *e.g.*:

   ```
   function f() {
       v = "hello world";
   }
   ```

   the variable `v` will automatically become a **global** variable.

So, since in your code you have written:

```
var msg = idIn 
    id = idIn
```

which means:

```
var msg = idIn;
id = idIn;
```

it makes `id` a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

When the comma is missing, javascript interpreter assumes you forgot `;` and add it by itself. The code now looks like this:

```
var msg = blabla;
id = x;
```

So the next statement becomes just `id = x;`. So javascript just put the value `x` in the existing variable `id` in the global's/parent's scope.

When the comma isn't missing, there's nothing for the interpreter, to assume - it knows you declare a **new** variable `id` with value `x`.

Javascript interpreter can't guess whether you missed a semicolon or a comma, it assumes you missed the semicolon, and in some cases it can produce unexpected results.

I'd suggest you to not continue write code like this, at least not intentionally.

Comment: Quick note: After automatic semicolon insertion `id` isn't local anymore, but a global variable.

Comment: Even if there's a variable `id` in the parent's scope? :0

Comment: Provided that this parent scope is the global scope `id = x` just mutates the global variable `id`

Comment: Oh, I just didn't assume that the `simulate` function was in the global scope, since it may have been copied from anywhere in his code, so I answered more generally. Ofcourse you're right though, thanks!